# Bash invisible arguments

Tags: bash, bash-scripting

Okay, I'm trying to do something tricky in bash. I'm writing a front-end method that will decide whether I am doing something like this:

```
 aws ecs update-service ... lots of args
```

or

```
 aws ecs create-service ... lots of args
```

It does this based on whether the service was previously created or not. That part isn't hard. What's tricky is that I'm going to use this in places where some of the arguments are optional. For instance, not all my services will have a load balancer. Some of these optional arguments might have spaces in them.

So I can do something like this:

```
local arg_name="--foo"
local arg_value="some value"

aws ecs create-service ... $arg_name $arg_value
```

And that's great if $arg_value doesn't contain spaces. But if it does, then it gets passed as multiple arguments rather than a single argument, which is problematic.  So I do this:

```
aws ecs create-service ... $arg_name "$arg_value"
```

But that actually can pass an empty arg. Without the quotes, it doesn't pass a thing, but with the quotes, it passes an empty string if arg_value is empty. The AWS CLI doesn't like that.

Other than going through absolutely everything I might have to do and make sure none of my arguments includes spaces (and some of them are JSON, so they might), I'm at a loss.

Ideas?

Comment: Read [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/444949/108618). Use an array. If you want to miss an argument then simply don't add it to the array (search for "build the command line piece-by-piece" in the linked answer).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski That was enough of a hint. I'd already tried several things with arrays, but it was a matter of adding double quotes in a few places that did it. I provided a complete answer below. Thank you so much. I should just be able to create an addnl_args array and add to it as necessary.

Answer (score 0):

With hints from the article from Kamil, I think I have an answer. I'd already tried a few things with arrays. Here's my testing:

```
L='{"foo": "bar"}'
args+=(--foo)
args+=("${L}")
e args: ${args[@]}
```

e is just a little C program that prints the args as such:

```
Arg #0 == e
Arg #1 == args:
Arg #2 == --foo
Arg #3 == {"foo":
Arg #4 == "bar"}
```

As you can see, so far, this solution doesn't work, as it still word-split.

So I did this:

```
e args: ${args[@]}
Arg #0 == e
Arg #1 == args:
Arg #2 == --foo
Arg #3 == {"foo": "bar"}
```

Then, to test a little further, I did this:

```
empty=()
e this is empty: "${empty[@]}"
Arg #0 == e
Arg #1 == this
Arg #2 == is
Arg #3 == empty:
```

So... the key parts are this:

```
args+=("${L}")
e args: "${args[@]}"
```

Note the quotes in both places.